# Как подсчитать количество значений в файле?

Tags: bash, grep, awk

Как найти в большом текстовом файле кол-во найденных значений?

Есть большой файл с логами сетевой активности. С помощью bash получил набор уникальных ip адресов. Как теперь прогнать этот список через файл и посчитать кол-во вхождений?

Например, можно найти кол-во найденных строк с определенным ip адресом:

```
cat report.log | awk '{print $11}' | grep 191.255.242.139 | wc -l
```

И есть ip адреса списком, вроде такого:

```
- 158.181.17.218
- 117.185.84.254
- 107.173.219.193
```

Comment: А в каком виде и как много ипишников?

Comment: `.. | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: *Useless use of cat*  и тут тоже. `awk` умеет и матчить, и считать. Короче, просто используйте `awk` и не морочьте голову со сложным языком shell.

Comment: @0andriy Добавте ответ, фантиков заработаете.

Comment: @0xdb, так толку-то? Пусть учится тот, кто задал вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

```
while read ip
do
    echo "found $ip $(grep -c $ip report.log) times"
done < ip.list
```

Осталось регулярку к ип, если дупликаты ип в одной строке не нужны.

Comment: *Useless use of cat* однако. Да и вообще шаблон `cat | while` очень тормозной.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, что натолкнули в правильное направление)
решил задачу таким путем:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/foler/report.log"
while read ip
do
echo "ip", "$ip"
echo "count"
cat report.log | awk '{print $11}' | grep $ip | wc -l
echo "---next---"
echo " "
done <"$file"
```

Comment: Какой ужас. Перепишите просто на `awk`.

Comment: У grep есть ключ -c считает вхожения.

Answer (score 1):

Если нет списка искомых адресов, создаем статистику расспределения:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IPV4_RE='\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b'

grep -oP $IPV4_RE "$1" \
    | sort \
    | uniq -c \
    | sort -rn
```

При наличие списка:

```
~$ while read -r ipv4; do printf "%s %s\n"  $(grep -c "$ipv4" ./report.txt) "$ipv4"; done < ip_list
```